# How to change dropdown list label text on click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu

I have a `<select>` element in my HTML that is bound via `ng-model` to an object in the scope.

Initially I want the dropdown to read "Group..." but when the user clicks on the control I want "Group..." to be renamed to "All" so that "Group..." can never be selected, in the same sense that sites use text boxes with default text that gives you a hint to what the form is for and disappears when it gets user focus (e.g. A "Search..." field).

Here is my JSFiddle example which isn't working as I expected: http://jsfiddle.net/TXPJZ/561/

I figured that `ng-onclick="myOptions[0].label = 'All'"` would work, it should change the value of the data structure that populates the dropdown and thus change the dropdown options but it doesn't.

How do I make this work like I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-click` is the directive you want, not ng-onclick. Using that it seems to work the way you want it to:

http://jsfiddle.net/TXPJZ/562/